# Lparallel.queue thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, queue, lisp, common-lisp

I may not be looking in the correct location for the [documentation of lparallel.queue](https://lparallel.org/api/queues/), but can we assume that those queues are thread-safe and that the queues take care of any locking/unlocking themselves, so that the user of the queues don't have to explicitly perform any locking/unlocking?  If this is documented somewhere, I would appreciate the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where it's specified, but looking at the code shows that the queue functions are indeed thread safe.

The queue functions all expand into calls to `DEFINE-LOCKING-FN` which in turns expands to a `DEFINE-LOCKING-FN/BASE` which results in a `DEFUN` of the function with the content wrapped in a `WITH-LOCK-HELD`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source code, the queues seem to be locked.

```
(define-queue-fn push-queue (object queue)
  push-cons-queue
  push-vector-queue)
```

...

```
(define-locking-fn push-cons-queue (object queue) (t cons-queue) (values) lock
  (with-cons-queue-slots (impl cvar) queue
    (push-raw-queue object impl)
    (when cvar
      (condition-notify cvar)))
  (values))
```

The unlocked functions have a separate name:

```
(define-queue-fn push-queue/no-lock (object queue)
  push-cons-queue/no-lock
  push-vector-queue/no-lock)
```